# Visual Studio, Collapse/Extends Regions ONLY shortcut

Tags: visual-studio, shortcut

Is there any shortcut to collapse/expand the regions ONLY? Meaning, if I have a region with 5 methods in it, and I hit collapse, the region will collapse, and when I will hit expand, the region will expand and I will see all 5 methods with the same state as it was before (collapsed/expanded).

Currently the shortcuts I found collapse ALL, or expand ALL, or substitutes the "All" word for the "Current" word.

I'm looking for a shortcut that will collapse only regions, and will not do anything to the other blocks inside a region. Same thing with expanding.

If there is no such thing, maybe someone found some visual extension to do it?

cheers
Lucas

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the following macros to expand/collapse the regions while leaving the expand/collapse state of individual methods as they were.

I found the macro [here](http://devstuffs.wordpress.com/2009/08/24/toggle-all-regions-in-visual-studio/). Note that I had to comment out the call to objSelection.EndOfDocument() from the CollapseAllRegions method for it to work properly (using Visual Studio 2010)

```
Imports EnvDTE
Imports System.Diagnostics
' Macros for improving keyboard support for "#region ... #endregion"
Public Module RegionTools
    ' Expands all regions in the current document
    Sub ExpandAllRegions()

        Dim objSelection As TextSelection ' Our selection object

        DTE.SuppressUI = True ' Disable UI while we do this
        objSelection = DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection() ' Hook up to the ActiveDocument's selection
        objSelection.StartOfDocument() ' Shoot to the start of the document

        ' Loop through the document finding all instances of #region. This action has the side benefit
        ' of actually zooming us to the text in question when it is found and ALSO expanding it since it
        ' is an outline.
        Do While objSelection.FindText("#region", vsFindOptions.vsFindOptionsMatchInHiddenText)
            ' This next command would be what we would normally do *IF* the find operation didn't do it for us.
            'DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.ToggleOutliningExpansion")
        Loop
        objSelection.StartOfDocument() ' Shoot us back to the start of the document
        DTE.SuppressUI = False ' Reenable the UI

        objSelection = Nothing ' Release our object

    End Sub

    ' Collapses all regions in the current document
    Sub CollapseAllRegions()

        Dim objSelection As TextSelection ' Our selection object

        ExpandAllRegions() ' Force the expansion of all regions

        DTE.SuppressUI = True ' Disable UI while we do this
        objSelection = DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection() ' Hook up to the ActiveDocument's selection
        objSelection.EndOfDocument() ' Shoot to the end of the document

        ' Find the first occurence of #region from the end of the document to the start of the document. Note:
        ' Note: Once a #region is "collapsed" .FindText only sees it's "textual descriptor" unless
        ' vsFindOptions.vsFindOptionsMatchInHiddenText is specified. So when a #region "My Class" is collapsed,
        ' .FindText would subsequently see the text 'My Class' instead of '#region "My Class"' for the subsequent
        ' passes and skip any regions already collapsed.
        Do While (objSelection.FindText("#region", vsFindOptions.vsFindOptionsBackwards))
            DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.ToggleOutliningExpansion") ' Collapse this #region
            'objSelection.EndOfDocument() ' Shoot back to the end of the document for
            ' another pass.
        Loop
        objSelection.StartOfDocument() ' All done, head back to the start of the doc
        DTE.SuppressUI = False ' Reenable the UI

        objSelection = Nothing ' Release our object

    End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: Any ideas for Visual Studio 2013; with no macro support..?

Answer (score 10):

why not simply hit

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>m</kbd> + <kbd>m</kbd>

while cursor in `#region regionname`

Comment: The command this executes is `Edit.ToggleOutliningExpansion`, by the way. It works while inside a region, method, class etc.

Answer (score 4):

I've written a free Visual Studio extension "[Menees VS Tools](http://www.menees.com/VSTools.htm)" that provides commands for "Collapse All Regions" and "Expand All Regions".  It's available for VS versions from 2003 to 2013.  The VS [2013](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f702b0aa-56c3-4ad8-91b4-5e653e0ba1c3) and VS [2012](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/42de112b-3ecf-4a9e-94f0-2b5efb053aa6) versions are available in the Visual Studio Gallery.