# Visual Studio 2010 randomly expands collapsed sections

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

My question is simply, is there a hotfix that will repair the bug which randomly expands collapsed sections in an aspx page after a few seconds. Once I re-collapse them it no longer collapses them, until I close the page and reopen it.

I'm running VS2010 vanilla (no service pack).

Thanks.

Comment: `Ctrl+M` `Ctrl+L` will toggle it. That's an easy way to collapse it all at once.

Answer (score 0):

ctrl+m, ctrl+s just collapse the current region. in java script you can use [this](http://blog.devarchive.net/2008/04/using-region-directive-with-javascript.html) extension and tools. but I think you need to a custom command, take a look at this:

[How to add commands to Visual Studio 2012?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12482620/how-to-add-commands-to-visual-studio-2012)

and for more information about more shortcuts in visual studio, check out this answer:

[Visual Studio, Collapse/Extends Regions ONLY shortcut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10396354/visual-studio-collapse-extends-regions-only-shortcut)