# How can I collapse current region with shortcut keys?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

`Ctrl-M` + `Ctrl-S` is collapsing current block. But this block can be a method.

Is there a short-cut key to collapse current region?

```
#region My Region
// group of methods
#endregion
```

Answer (score 11):

While your cursor is pointing @ `#region regionname` use the hot keys

> ctrl + m + m

I think you should look at this post once [Visual Studio, Collapse/Extends Regions ONLY shortcut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10396354/visual-studio-collapse-extends-regions-only-shortcut)

Comment: Cursor is typically not over the `#region regionname`, but thanks for the link. My question seems a duplicate of that one.

Comment: @serdar, typically what you are trying to achieve can't be done without some extra plug-in/extensions as answered in that linked post.

Answer (score 2):

Why not simply hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>, <kbd>M</kbd> while cursor in `#region regionname`