# VisualStudio 2019 - expand all regions below and including

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

Is there a command/macro/keyboard shortcut that will expand the region where the cursor is and expand *all* collapsed regions inside it (recursively) ? if not can that be achieved ?

Answer (score 5):

## Short answer

As far as I know - No. There isn't a single shortcut that does that.

## How to implement it by yourself

It's quite easy to create a plugin for Visual Studio that does exactly that:

1. Get the cursor location.
2. Store the 'start' and 'end' line numbers
3. For each line:

   - If it contains a region - expand it.

Few examples to begin with:

- https://github.com/LeonalaDiantes/RegionsWasher
- https://github.com/dnperfors/RegionExpander
- https://github.com/fsdsabel/ExpandRegions
- https://github.com/pauljmelia/regionsareevil
- https://github.com/yasam100/CodeRegionsSnippets-VSExtension

Some of the projects are very close to the thing you have in mind, so you might even fork it and do your changes.

:-)

## Another option

you might get the same result by using [Macros for Visual Studio](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioPlatformTeam.MacrosforVisualStudio) Editor/Recorder:

And then, write a macro [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12447097/426315) or maybe even record the steps you like to "run".

IMO, with recording and playing it will be a little harder to achieve.
but I'll be happy to be proved wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, the following worked for me without having to make a macro or a plugin. Note, this is only a partial solution to the problem. I got it to expand recursively underneath a function, but I'm not sure how to reverse it (i.e. recursively collapse everything under the function again). To recursively collapse everything again, I could only figure to use (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>), which collapses/expands everything in your file, but then you have to drill back down to the function you want.

Firstly, I got everything in a collapsed state by pressing (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>).  You may have to use that combination twice to get everything to collapse. Then I expanded a class and drilled down to the function I wanted to work on.

With the function in its collapsed state, I highlighted the single collapsed row it was on and pressed (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>).

Doing so recursively expanded everything under the function.

I hope this partial solution helps someone who doesn't want to make a macro or plugin.

Answer (score -1):

I believe `ctrl + k` followed by `ctrl+]` should *unfold* all subregions

replacing the `]` with `[` should *fold* all subregions.